# How to pass GWT widget parameters to JSP?

Tags: jsp, gwt

I am developing a loginform in GWT where the authentication parameters are needed to be passed to jsp page. I could navigate to the jsp page using

```
Window.Location.assign(url);
```

with my jsp page in the war directory but it would not execute the authentication logic, cause it couldn't identify the parameters. Am I missing any import statement? Please help me

Comment: It is not the best way to submit auth parameters. You can use simple post request.

Answer (score 0):

Given the method you want to use to navigate to the url, I would append the parameters as part of the URL  ( www.host.com/login.jsp?param=1

But if you are passing in User Id and password I would use a different method.  At least put them in the body of the http request (like a POST) and use https.